# multiplication of consecutive prime numbers in the form $4k +3$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, proof-writing

How can I prove that prime numbers beginning with $2$, multiplied with the next consecutive prime plus $1$, $2\times3\times5\times7\times\cdots+1$, will give the form $4K+3$?

Answer (score 3):

Forget the +1, how can you show that 2x3x5x7... will give the form 4K+2;
or that 
3x5x7x11... will give the form 2K+1 ?

Comment: I know intuitively that 3x5x7x11...will give an odd number since 2 is the only even prime. I also know 2k+1 is another way to write an odd number. However how do I show 3x5x7x11... = 2k +1 mathematically?

Comment: You know that an odd times an odd equals an odd.  Use induction to show that 3x5x...xp is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P_n$ denote the $n$th prime. We wish to show $$\Big(\prod_{i=1}^nP_i\Big)-2\equiv 0\pmod 4. $$ We will proceed via induction.

Let $n=3$ and the result follows ($28=4\times7$). Assume for $n=k$ $$\Big(\prod_{i=1}^kP_i\Big)-2\pmod4 \implies \exists L\in \mathbb{Z}:\prod_{i=1}^kP_i=4L+2. $$ Consider now $n=k+1$. We have \begin{align}\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}P_i\Big)-2=&P_{k+1}\Big(\prod_{i=1}^kP_i\Big)-2\\=&2P_{k+1}(2L+1)+2\\ =&2\big(P_{k+1}(2L+1)+1\big).\end{align} We recognize that both $P_{k+1}$ and $2L+1$ must be odd. Consequently, the product $(P_{k+1})(2L+1)$ is also odd and can be written in the form $2m-1:m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore, $$\Big(\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}P_i\Big)-2=2(2m-1+1)=4m. $$ It then follows that $$\Big(\prod_{i=1}^nP_i\Big)-2\equiv 0\pmod4\ \text{for}\ n>i.$$